# put php function in seperate file and call from another

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have to connect to db many times, So i thought to put db connecting code in anothe file called functions.php as

```
<?php
function connect_db(){
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
}
?>
```

when i want to connect i inserted connect_db() in another file as,

```
try {
connect_db();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE url= :url');
```

and i got an error..

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /...

It's a scoping error right? but i heard making it global is not good. can you tell me how to insert it properly?

thanks.

Comment: Your error is here: `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbname', 'usr', 'pass');`, should be `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname="dbname", 'usr', 'pass');`

Comment: @k102 Not really, the problem is that `$conn` outside of `connect_db()` is implied `null`, which is the non-object the error refers to.

Comment: @Jack oh, I see. I've stopped on the first error noticed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the object in your function, otherwise it's just a local variable inside the function that gets purged once the function ends.

```
function connect_db()
{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

    return $conn;
}

$conn = connect_db();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an issue with the scope - `$conn` is only available within the function. You need to return it:

```
function connect_db(){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    return $conn;
}
```

And then when you call the function:

```
$conn = connect_db();
```

Answer (score -1):

You  can try like it..

first.php

```
<?php
   function connect_db(){ 
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbname', 'usr', 'pass');
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
   return $con;  
   }
  ?>
```

second.php

```
    <?php
      include('first.php');
      connect_db();
     ?>
```